# bad interpreter no such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Thank you for reviewing my shell script i am producing this error but not sure why it is not running. I am a noob when it comes to shell scripting. Please help. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#This script creates the log files based on the current date and hour

#Variables for managing the logs
LOG_DIRECTORY=/var/log;                 export LOG_DIRECTORY
LOG_DIRECTORY_FILE=/var/log/secure;     export LOG_DIRECTORY_FILE
MY_LOG_DIRECTORY=$LOG_DIRECTORY/mylogs; export MY_LOG_DIRECTORY
MY_LOG_FILE=$MY_LOG_DIRECTORY/mylog-`date +%m-%d-%H`;   export MY_LOG_FILE
EXPRESSTION=`date '+%b %d %H'`;                     export MY_LOG_FILE


#Checks if mylog directory exists.If not, then creates it
if [ ! -d "$MY_LOG_DIRECTORY" ]; then
mkdir -p $MY_LOG_DIRECTORY
fi

#Scripts exits successfully, If the log already exists
if [ -f "$MY_LOG_FILE" ]; then
echo "Log file already exists. Nothing is written to log";
exit 0;
fi

#grep the contents to the log file
grep "^$EXPRESSTION" $LOG_DIRECTORY_FILE >> $MY_LOG_FILE
echo "New myLog file created successfully"
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a UNIX text file, not a DOS text file?

Comment: ...if it were a DOS file, then you'd have CRLF newlines, so the OS would be trying to run `/bin/bash$'\r'`, not `/bin/bash`, thus the obvious file not found.

Comment: i need to extract the dates data from /var/log/secure

Comment: so how do i make it work?

Comment: Does your system have bash in `/bin`? What is the result of `file /bin/bash`?

Comment: If you want to confirm or deny the theory, by the way, `cat -A yourscript | head -n 1` (assuming GNU cat) and give us the first line, exactly as printed. If it's precisely `#!/bin/bash$`, with no other characters, then it's time to look at whether `/bin/bash` is actually present and working.

Comment: This script doesn't use any bashisms, by the way, so you could also use `#!/bin/sh` if you don't have a `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Not relevant to your problem, but since you're using bash you can combine the `export` with the assignments. For example, rather than `foo=bar; exort foo` you can write `export foo=bar`. But as far as I can tell you don't actually need to `export` any of those variables.

Comment: @KeithThompson, indeed, though I don't see anything here that would make `export` necessary, useful or even helpful; the external commands being run don't look at the environment for arguments, so just taking out the `export`s is probably the saner action.

Comment: (while we're talking issues unrelated to the bug at hand, by convention all-caps variable names are reserved for environment variables and builtins; using names with at least one lower-case letter prevents overwriting a builtin or an environment variable by mistake).

Comment: BTW, if your `bash` interpreter is located somewhere other than `/bin/bash`, but there's a `/bin/env`, you can use `#!/bin/env bash`.

Comment: What editor are you using? If you say _Windows' Notepad_, I'll personally come over and dope slap you. Notepad is not a program editor. Use something like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org). If I know the editor, I can tell you how to fix this in the editor. Also, is this checked into a repository and then checked out on the server? Some allow you to make sure that the EOL character is Unix's `LF` only instead of Windows `CRLF`.

Answer (score 1):

Your script needs to be saved as a UNIX text file.

Try running `dos2unix` on it, or open it up in vim and run `:set fileformat=unix` and save.

If you don't have dos2unix, and aren't comfortable with vim, you can use perl:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n?/\n/g' your-script-filename
```

Comment: i ran that and it did nothing to my script

Comment: It won't do anything *visible*. If you used `cat -A yourscript` (or any other command that shows hidden characters) before and after, you'd see the difference.

Comment: @johndoe: So, did you try `cat -A`? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

`"bad interpreter no such file or directory"` error indicates `/bin/bash` does not exist. 


Try to run script as

`$ sh log.sh`


 OR use some other available shell interpreter (e.g `/bin/sh` , `/bin/ksh`) instead of `/bin/bash`